# Google Sheets or Excel, how can I seperate out/sort this data most easily?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Say I have some data like this - provided to me in the following format

| Customer Name | SomeNumber |
| --- | --- |
| john smith | 1.1 |
| john smith | 2.1 |
| james johnson | 1.1 |
| jack foley | 2.1 |
| jimbob jones | 1.1 |
| jimbob jones | 2.1 |
| jimbob jones | 3.1 |
| alex jefferson | 1.1 |
| bob jameson | 2.1 |
| bob jameson | 3.1 |
| joe joleson | 3.1 |

and so on.

What I need:

List of customers that have 1.1  or 2.1, but not 3.1

list of customers that have 3.1 only

List of customers have either (1.1 or 2.1), and also 3.1

What's the easiest (least manual work) way to go about this?

Comment: instead of "saying" that you have some data "like this", just show us what your data is like.  Here is a blank sheet you can paste into that will make it easier to help.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JJgl7Lfwkq-r2tPYIvjZt3IT_wsU2fr2MzXIsyRqj1s/edit

Comment: thank you! I have updated the given sheet.

Comment: i should add that the full dataset is around 500 rows so I'd prefer to avoid any solution that requires me to manually go through the data and add something to a new column for example.

Comment: Can you provide an expected output? the description list customers is quite generic? do you want to have a list of unique names based on the conditions mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

My idea, demonstrated in cell E2 on [this sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JJgl7Lfwkq-r2tPYIvjZt3IT_wsU2fr2MzXIsyRqj1s/edit#gid=2100307022), is to use different "places" in a number to add up in a query to give you a sort of "code" that will indicate which of the various versions are associated with a given name.

Here is the formula I wrote that gives the basic structure and query result.  You would add conditions to that query string to choose the rows you were interested in.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:A,MMULT(N(B2:B={3.1,2.1,1.1}),{100;10;1})},"select Col1,SUM(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### List of customers that have 1.1 or 2.1, but not 3.1

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, (B2:B=1.1)+(B2:B=2.1), 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, JOIN("|", FILTER(A:A, B:B=3.1))))))
```

---

> ### list of customers that have 3.1 only

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, B2:B=3.1, 
 NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, JOIN("|", FILTER(A:A, (B:B=1.1)+(B:B=2.1)))))))
```

---

> ### List of customers have either (1.1 or 2.1), and also 3.1

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, B2:B=3.1, 
 REGEXMATCH(A2:A, JOIN("|", FILTER(A:A, (B:B=1.1)+(B:B=2.1))))))
```